# How to animate Silverlight 4 ListBox items when the bound data is sorted?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, animation, listbox

I'm trying to find out exactly what happens when the data bound with ItemsSource changes. So which method should I override to be able to make the items animate to their new positions in the sorted list?

From what I found out so far I might have to hijack the LayoutUpdated of the ScrollViewer inside the ListBox? How do I find out what happens there in order to be able to attach an animation to the ListBoxItems' position assignments?

Actually it would be even nicer to do this with some attached triggers and behaviors and not having to extend the ListBox class.

Edit: as it turned out both PagedCollectionView and CollectionViewSource destroys and recreates the item list on sorting, so rearranging the list with an animation doesn't seem to be possible without either implementing sorting manually by moving existing items around in the list or to create some sort of item buffer, both of which sounding like a possible source of weird bugs and performance bottleneck. If anyone has a working solution to these though I'd be glad to get any pointers!